# wpf add style property to button default style

Tags: c#, wpf

Im using the [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) framework for my wpf window. Now the default button's of MahApps.Metro looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to change the style to this:

[image]

If I want to create this button I have to use this style property `Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}"`. But I dont want to write this in every Button, I want to create a default button design.

---

Now I added to my `app.xaml` file this code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If I create a setter like this:

`<Setter Property="Style" Value="Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}"/>`, I get 10 error's.

How can I set `<Setter Property="Style" Value="Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}"/>` for every button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new style based on another one :

```
<!-- based on the current generic style -->
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">

<!-- based on a specific style -->
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) I used this code: `<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}">`, with StaticResource.